# Strange behavior of GCP Load Balancer

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I had a strange behavior with google global lb. On the one zone traffic evenly , but on other zone with same load traffic loads pods not evenly. Configs at zones are the same. Can it appears to gcp load balancer config or core of gcp lb?  [not evenly loaded zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuGgX.png)

[more evenly loaded zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF0w0.png)

Comment: Are you using GKE Ingress here?  Can you share your deployment specs?